# How get Current point

Tags: matlab-guide

Good morning,
I have a aplicattion with:

```
set(gcf,'WindowButtonMotionFcn',{@mousecaptureLC});
```

where I get the x and y coordinates from mousecaptureLC function.

```
function  mousecaptureLC(src, eventdata)

pos = get(gca, 'CurrentPoint'); % Axes with a image - (Axes1)
x = pos(1, 1); 
y = pos(1, 2); % its working very well
```

This values are send to labels text in my GUI:

```
hfig1 = findobj('Tag','lbl_x');
handles = guidata(hfig1);
hfig2 = findobj('Tag','lbl_y');
handles = guidata(hfig2);
set(handles.lbl_x, 'string', sprintf('X: %1.0f  ', x)); 
set(handles.lbl_y, 'string', sprintf('Y: %1.0f  ', y));
```

**I need to do:**

I need to use the x values in other Axes, ie (Axes2), in real time. I want to plot  the columns image in Axes2 by moving the mouse.

**The Problem:**
in side the mousecaptureLC(), when I get the handle of axes2  my motion function leave to working.

```
h = gcf;
Axes2 = findobj(h,'Tag','Axes2');
axes(Axes2)
```

It works by clicking. Its not working more by movement mouse.

1) I tried to get the values from label text (in side GUI function), but not work of dynamic way. Work by click.

someone can help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

worked using only the handle of the axes2 within the plot function

plot(handles.Axes2,x, y)